# Rails AJAX Jquery Loop Through Object To Display Error Validations

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, devise

I have a rails app using devise and some custom error validations for modal pop-over forms.

**1. In my app/assest/javascripts/application.js I have the JQuery AJAX setup to process a form submit and show error validations returned from override devise RegistrationsController, like so:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('submit', '#reg_form', function(event){
    var form = $('button[type=submit]').parent('form');
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      type: "PUT",
      url: form.attr('action'),
      dataType: 'JSON',
      data: form.serialize(),
      success: function(data){
        console.log("some data" + data);
      },
      error: function(data){
        $("#error_display_test").html("<p style='color:red;font-weight:bold'>You have entered and invalid email or password.</p>");
        $("input#reg_email").addClass("errors");
        $("input#reg_password").addClass("errors");
        $("input#reg_full_name").addClass("errors");
        var errors = data.responseText;
        var json = JSON.parse(data.responseText);
        console.log(json)
        var er ='<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>';
        **for (var key in json) {
            // skip loop if the property is from prototype
            if (!json.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;

            var obj = json[key];
            for (var prop in obj) {
                // skip loop if the property is from prototype
                if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue;
                // your code
                er += '<li>' + prop + " = " + obj[prop] + '</li>';
            }
            er+='</div>';
            $("#error_display_test2").html(er);**
        }
      },
    });
  });
});
```

**2. The SessionsController (override for devise) has a do block to format the output to json like so:**

```
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { respond_with @user }
    format.js
    format.json { render json: @user.resource.errors.full_messages }
  end
```

**3. The error validation object returned in console.log is:**

```
Object {error: "You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."}
```

**4. THE ISSUE: When displaying in my form modal view after ajax form error is called, it appears like so:**

```
0 = Y
1 = o
2 = u
3 =
4 = n
5 = e
6 = e
7 = d
8 =
9 = t
10 = o
11 =
12 = s
13 = i
14 = g
15 = n
16 =
17 = i
18 = n
```

**Final Question: Why is the happening? I am simply trying to display an array of error objects, not each character within the object key and object property.**